# Usage of Could have

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

> It’s ten o’clock. They **could have** arrived now.

Does this “could have” indicates they “could have” but they didn’t? If my conclusion is correct, Are there anyother possible interpretations or not?

Comment: There's no way of knowing if they arrived or not at the time that sentence is said. It only means *might have* or *are capable of having*. Even *should have* doesn't mean certainty.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have studied that could+ have is used for past ability while indicating that action did not take place. For example “I could have revealed the secret” indicatesI could have, but I did not. Is this wrong? Or the same interpretation is not possible in the question given by me?

Comment: No, that's not right. (1) *I could have revealed the secret, and I did!.* (2) *I could have revealed the secret, but I didn't!* The use of *could* itself says nothing aside from capability and possibility.

Comment: That's right. They could have arrived and be waiting for you.

Comment: The key as ever, is context - that should make it clear whether the author knows the answer or not. The author might be saying "why aren't they here yet?" or they might be saying "I presume that they HAVE arrived there."

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that “now” is present tense, whereas “could have” is past tense.

What that sentence seems to be saying is that they could have arrived at this precise moment in the present, which negates the past tense of “could have”.

What you would actually say is:

> They could have arrived **by** now.

If you were in the place of their possible arrival, awaiting them, then more idiomatically you would hear:

> They could have **been here** by now.